# Need help installing Brother HL 2270dw printer

Tags: installation, drivers, printing

Greetings. I am new to Linux and Ubuntu.

I have really tried to install our new printer. I have been working with these instructions from Brother: http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html

Everything seems OK through Step 4. I do not understand Step 5. If I type `/etc/printcap` the response is `permission denied`. If I type: `sudo /etc/printcap` then the response is `command not found`.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me get this printer installed and working wirelessly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the file `/etc/printcap`, as described in step 5-2 of your link.

You can type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/printcap
```

If that command does not work, you can edit the file with the terminal editor `nano` (the easiest for beginners):

```
sudo nano /etc/printcap
```

And then edit the file as described in the manual.

Comment: The link says if CUPS is installed to use a different method. I suggest you follow that process instead.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about step 5, editing the file.

Comment: Thank you chaos! That helped. Now, 5.3 does not work.

Comment: How would I know if CUPS is installed?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: bash: /etc/init.d/lpr: No such file or directory

Comment: That was after entering: /etc/init.d/lpr restart